# Coloring a world map

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, shading, mapping

I'm trying to create a graphic with tikz on latex/overleaf of a world map based on regionally disaggregated data, so I want e.g. all countries that belong to Eastern Europe to have the same colour, since they have the same value of the variable. The variable is scaled from 0 to 100, with six different values (for six regions).
This is the blanco map I have been working with: https://gitlab.com/conradolandia/WorldMap-Tikz.

So far, I have managed to attribute different values to countries, giving them a different shade, but so far these are different shades of the same colour, in my case orange. I have simply translated a country's score on the variable (e.g. 70) to the colour satisfaction (e.g. 70). However, for better visualisation, I would like the colours to rank from orange (with a satisfaction of 10) to violet (s. of 90). People with similar issues seem to be working with pgfplot, but since I am not trying to create a plot I am a bit lost as to how I would manage with the grading and also with adding a legend scale to explain the colours. I was wondering of xcolors could be a solution, but as an absolute beginner, I wouldn't know how to apply it to my issue. Any ideas?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: pgfplots uses color cycles, not 100 colors,, but a list of thiem (probably a tikz array).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the color syntax `colorone!number!colortwo` as described in the [xcolor manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) (see examples on page 33), in this case `fill=orange!#2!violet`. This causes a color gradient from violet to orange.

Alternatively, you can define a color series and set the number of steps (here 100), see page 35. In that case you get various different colors. Note that the `hsb` models are not supported by PGF/TikZ, in the code below an `rgb` model is used.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=2\linewidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\input{World}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{set state val/.style args={#1/#2}{#1={fill=orange!#2!violet}}}
\tikzset{set state val/.list={Greenland/0,Colombia/16,Canada/33,Russia/50,Brazil/66,Mexico/83.3,India/99}}
\WORLD[every state={draw=white, thick, fill=black!20}]
\end{tikzpicture}

\definecolorseries{countrycolors}{rgb}{step}[rgb]{.95,.85,.55}{.17,.47,.37}
\resetcolorseries[100]{countrycolors}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{set state val/.style args={#1/#2}{#1={fill=countrycolors!![#2]}}}
\tikzset{set state val/.list={Greenland/0,Colombia/16,Canada/33,Russia/50,Brazil/66,Mexico/83.3,India/99}}
\WORLD[every state={draw=white, thick, fill=black!20}]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]